# click function in react was calling more than once even and there is no strict mode used in index files

Tags: reactjs

```
renderQuestionAndAnswers() {
    const { questionsAndAnswers, qAndALoader } = this.state;

    const { showQAValdiationMessage, resetFeilds } = this.props;

    if (questionsAndAnswers.length !== 0) {
      return questionsAndAnswers.map((question) => {
        return (   
          <div 
            key={question.question_id}
            className="col-sm-6 pdg-rgt_0 "
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log("on click event");
              this.setState({
                selectedQuestion: question.question_id
              },()=>console.log('selected questions1',this.state.selectedQuestion))
            }
            }                 
          >
            <span className="mrgn-btm-0 input-title form-field-text">
              {question.question}
            </span>
            {question.is_mandatory ? (
              <span className="clr-46bbb3">*</span>
            ) : (
                <span className="mrgn-btm-0 input-title form-field-text">
                  &nbsp;(Optional)
                </span>
              )}
            <QuestionAndAnswers
              key={question.question_id}
              answers={question.answers}
              resetFeilds={resetFeilds}
              questionid={question.question_id}
              postAnswer={(answerId) =>
                this.populateQuestionAndAnswer(answerId)
              }
              mandatory={question.is_mandatory}
            />{' '}
            {showQAValdiationMessage &&
              question.validation_error &&
              question.is_mandatory && (
                <span className="invalid-error-msg">
                  This feild is mandatory
                </span>
              )}
          </div>
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

In the above lines code the on click function was triggred twice and resulting it in printing the twice and also the set state was triggering twice , where as the with in the index.js file i was not using react.strict mode , but still don`t know why my click function was being trigered twice, which is allowing the setstate to have null some times.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate function and then call then from your onClick handler like this

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log("on click event");
              this.setState({
                selectedQuestion: question.question_id
              },()=>console.log('selected questions1',this.state.selectedQuestion))
            }
```

and call it like this

```
onClick={handleChange}
```